# Is it possible to use StructuredTool with any Agent?

Tags: langchain

I am was trying to figure out a way to use `StructuredTool` as a multi-input Tool and used from an Agent; for example, an `ZeroShotAgent`.
Sadly, looks like all the agents are defined to use `Tool[]` instead of `StructuredTool[ ]` or `ObjectTool[ ]`. Is there any way I can do that?

This is my code, the final Tool (**QuerySpecificFieldSupabaseTool**) is an `StructuredTool` which is incompatible with the Agents.

```
export class SupabaseToolkit extends Toolkit {
    tools: Tool[];
    cli: SupabaseClient
    dialect = "supabase"

    constructor(cli: SupabaseClient) {
        super()
        this.cli = cli
        this.tools = [
            new QuerySupabaseTool(cli),
            new ListTablesSupabaseTool(cli),
            new ListFieldsSupabaseTool(cli),
            new QuerySpecificFieldSupabaseTool(cli),
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of 02 May 2023** (likely subject to change):
Structured Tools can only accept one string argument in order to be compatible with most existing Agents. The one Agent than can accept a structured tool with multiple arguments is the `STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION` Agent type, see docs [here](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/agents/tools/multi_input_tool.html).

This is discussed in [the blog post that introduces Structured Tools](https://blog.langchain.dev/structured-tools/).

> Q: Can I use structured tools with existing agents?
>
> A: If your structured tool accepts one string argument: YES, it will still work with existing agents. However, structured tool with more than one argument are not directly compatible with the following agents without further customization:
>
> `zero-shot-react-description`
> `react-docstore`
> `self-ask-with-search`
> `conversational-react-description`
> `chat-zero-shot-react-description`
> `chat-conversational-react-description`

Comment: It make sense. I was experimenting with my own `Custom StructuredTools` which leverage `zod schemas`. Thank you.